# Merging unallocated partition in usb drive

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I am totally new to linux. I have a 1 GB USB pen drive. Some windows virus created a 1.4MB partition in it and copied itself in it. I want to delete that partition or merge it with the rest of the drive space.
I would've posted screenshot, but that is not allowed :(

Answer (score 0):

- Open GParted.
- Select the device in the top right corner.
- Find the partition in the list below.
- Right click and select "Delete". If this option is inaccessible, try unmounting (also from right click menu) before deleting.

Afterwards, you may want to resize the main partition to take up all the space on the pen drive.